# Can't disable button

Tags: objective-c, uikit

Ok, I've been looking through forums the past couple of days and trying every way that I can to disable this button, but nothing is working.  I'm assuming that it's just some syntax I need due to the way that I'm calling the view controller.  I can change label texts, but not alter buttons in any way.  Here's what I have tried to change the button, but nothing is working:

in my .h file, linked with the button with control-drag:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnDelete;
```

and here is what I have put in my .m file in the viewDidLoad and also tried in viewDidAppear:

```
_btnDelete.enabled=false;
_btnDelete.hidden=true;
_btnDelete.userInteractionEnabled=false;
[_btnDelete setEnabled:NO];
[btnDelete setAlpha:0.0];
[btnDelete setNeedsDisplay];
```

None of these appear to do anything to the button.

Here is how I am calling the view controller that has the button on it.

```
Detail *Det = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];
[Det setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:Det animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I also tried to add the following lines right after the above, just to see if that would work, but it did not.

```
Det.btnDelete.enabled=false;
Det.btnDelete.hidden=true;
```

Like I said, I've went through forums and tried to find diff ways to modify the button, but nothing is working.  The button is not attributed, just plain text.  I cannot modify the button in any way that I can see, but I can modify other controls on the page, like labels, just fine.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your outlet is connected?  http://imgur.com/a/z2oIu

Little circle on the left should be filled in

Comment: `_btnDelete` is probably `nil`. This is what a debugger is for. You should know the problem in about 4 seconds (literally) of using the debugger instead of simply guessing and trying different things for days.

Comment: I see the connection when I look at the button details.  I will test for nil with a breakpoint now.  I do android dev also and a nil reference in that results in a gpf for the app, guess I assumed it would do the same in xcode.  lol.  testing it now

Comment: @#$@#@#!!!!  I can't believe it was that simple.  At some point the connection got broken.  I deleted the link and re-cntrl-dragged it and it works now.  Thanks for the help.  I should have tried that!

Comment: It has nothing to do with Xcode. It's Objective-C. It's perfectly valid to call methods and access properties of `nil` pointers.

Comment: Why the -1 vote?  Sorry, still a bit new to posting here.